# $a_{1}=1$, $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+f(n)$. Prove that $a_{n}$ isn't bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I came up with $a_{n}=1+f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+\ldots+f(n-1)>1+(n-1)f(n-1)$
As $n$ approaches infinity $n-1$ goes to infinity but $f(n)$ may approach $0$
So from here I do not get any information
($f(n)$ is decreasing function that's always equal to positive values)

Comment: Do you mean it is not necessarily bounded?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(n)= \frac{1}{n^2}$, then $(a_n)$ is bounded.

If $f(n)= \frac{1}{n}$, then $(a_n)$ is not bounded.